# What is The Best Practice for Custom Plugin Files Placement

Tags: 9, plugins

I'm going to create a custom plugin type, so I need to create a plugin manager, plugin base, plugin Interface and a plugin annotation, the annotations goes to `ModuleRoot/src/Annotation` but for the rest I saw 2 approaches

- Place PluginManager, PluginBase and PluginInterface in `moduleRoot/src`
- Place PluginManager, PluginBase and PluginInterface in `moduleRoot/src/Plugin`

but I couldn't resolve which one is the best practice?

Comment: IMO for namespacing and organization I put them under Plugin.

Comment: Neither one is better practice, different people will tell you different things based on their own preferences. Person A will say _it's better for `PluginManager` not to be in the `Plugin` subfolder, because it's not a Plugin_. Person B will tell you what @Kevin mentioned above. They're both fine